# How to estimate the difference between two datetimes in minutes

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two datetime fields

```
ts1                     ts2
2020-09-10 14:24:17     2019-07-22 09:14:41
```

How may I calculate ts1-ts2 in minutes?

```
SELECT ts1-ts2 
from test_tables_1
```

What is the correct way to get the number of minutes between the two datetimes?

Comment: `DATEDIFF(mi, ts1, ts2)`

Comment: The official SQL Server documentation lists all the datetime functions available.

Comment: 'DATEIFF' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: @john check your spelling. DATE*D*IFF not DATEIFF.

Comment: OMG thank you Justin!!!!!!!! Shame to ask this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is from: [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

`DATEDIFF ( datepart , startdate , enddate )`

So in your case `SELECT DATEDIFF(mi,ts1,ts2) AS 'Difference' FROM test_tables_1`